# Queue not being processed when setup with bridge poller and task executor

Tags: multithreading, spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to setup a queue that would be polled by one poller thread and its contents handed over to some service invoked via dispatcher & taskExecutor. The below code is what i came up with

```
<int:channel id="dataInQueue">
    <int:priority-queue capacity="100" />
</int:channel>

<int:bridge input-channel="dataInQueue" output-channel="dataInProcesingQueue">
    <int:poller receive-timeout="5000" fixed-rate="500" task-executor="taskScheduler" />
</int:bridge>   

<int:router input-channel="dataInProcesingQueue" expression="payload.runType.id">
    <int:mapping value="1" channel="processingQ1"/>
</int:router>   

<int:channel id="processingQ1" >
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
</int:channel>

<int:chain input-channel="processingQ1" output-channel="outChannel">
    <int:service-activator ref="myService"  />
</int:chain>    

<bean id="taskExecutor"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="My-TaskExecutor" />                
</bean>
<bean id="taskScheduler"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler">
        <property name="poolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="My-TaskScheduler" />
</bean>
```

unfortunately this doesn't work. If I put a message on the queue, I don't see it being processed. On the other hand, if I replace taskExecutor & taskScheduler with *org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor* implementation then everything starts to work.
It looks like the problem is somewhere with my thread pool configuration but i can't see any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove this `task-executor="taskScheduler"`.

The poller already uses the inbuilt `taskScheduler` internally; the `task-executor` attribute is for when you want to immediately hand off to another thread.

It's not immediately clear why that would cause your app to not work, but it's redundant for the scheduler to hand off to itself.

Simply remove it and the scheduler will hand off to your executor after the router.

Or, set `task-executor="taskExecutor"` on the poller and remove the dispatcher on the `processingQ1` - you don't need two handoffs.

**EDIT:**

That said, I just tried your scenario and it works ok for me (I see the double handoff)...

```
11:05:43.623 DEBUG [My-TaskScheduler4][org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter] Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={id=a23d369b-a7c7-50d6-2209-6df83e51f380, timestamp=1422720343623}]
11:05:43.628 DEBUG [My-TaskScheduler15][org.springframework.integration.channel.PriorityChannel] postReceive on channel 'dataInQueue', message: GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={id=a23d369b-a7c7-50d6-2209-6df83e51f380, timestamp=1422720343623}]
11:05:43.628 DEBUG [My-TaskScheduler4][org.springframework.integration.channel.PriorityChannel] postSend (sent=true) on channel 'dataInQueue', message: GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={id=a23d369b-a7c7-50d6-2209-6df83e51f380, timestamp=1422720343623}]
11:05:43.629 DEBUG [My-TaskScheduler15][org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer] Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={id=a23d369b-a7c7-50d6-2209-6df83e51f380, timestamp=1422720343623}]
11:05:43.629 DEBUG [My-TaskScheduler15][org.springframework.integration.handler.BridgeHandler] org.springframework.integration.handler.BridgeHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={id=a23d369b-a7c7-50d6-2209-6df83e51f380, timestamp=1422720343623}]
11:05:43.630 DEBUG [My-TaskScheduler15][org.springframework.integration.channel.ExecutorChannel] postSend (sent=true) on channel 'toRabbit', message: GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={id=a23d369b-a7c7-50d6-2209-6df83e51f380, timestamp=1422720343623}]
11:05:43.631 DEBUG [My-TaskExecutor1][org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint] org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={id=a23d369b-a7c7-50d6-2209-6df83e51f380, timestamp=1422720343623}]
```

If it still doesn't work after my suggestion, I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging (including the thread name) and track the handoff.

Comment: WOW!   Thank you!!!!!   That is been driving me crazy.   I thought it seems like Spring Batch jobs were interfering but told me self that was crazy.